# Qt->QGraphicsView->QGraphicsItem resizing

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm pretty new to QGraphicsView in Qt.

As far as I can tell there is no built in way to resize a QGraphicsItem in a scene with a mouse.

What I'm looking for is to be able to resize a QGraphicsRectItem by either dragging out the corners or the edges on screen.

Is there a simple way to do that? Is there a library or a piece of code somewhere online that implements this functionality?

I'm currently using Qt 4.5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/forum/f-qt-programming-2/t-resize-a-qgraphicsitem-13296.html) thread has a similar question. You will have to manually resize the item after intercepting the mousemove events. You can get the 'pos' from 'event' argument like:-

```
QPointF pt = event->pos()
```

Use this point 'pt' for resizing to the correct location.

Also lookup the '[Elastic Nodes](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtjambi-4.4/html/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-elasticnodes-code.html)' application in Qt Demos application. This will help.