# How do you draw a grid and rectangles in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, tkinter, glade

What Python-related code (PyGTK, Glade, Tkinter, PyQT, wxPython, Cairo, ...) could you easily use to create a GUI to do some or all of the following?

1. Part of the GUI has an immovable square grid.
2. The user can press a button to create a resizable rectangle.
3. The user can drag the rectangle anywhere on the grid, and it will snap to the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DiagramScene Eaxmple that comes with PyQt implements much of the functionality you want. It has a fixed background grid, you can create a rectangle object but it's not resizable and doesn't snap to grid.

This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072047/qt-qgraphicsview-qgraphicsitem-resizing) has advice on resizing graphical objects with the mouse. It's for C++ Qt but the technique should be easy to replicate in PyQt.

For snap-to-grid I don't think there is any built-in functionality. You would probably need to reimplement the itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) function. Pseudocode:

```
if (object not possitioned exactly on the grid):
    (possition the item on the grid)
```

Repossitioning the item will cause itemChange to get called again, but that's ok because the item will be possitioned correctly and won't be moved again, so you'll not be stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: The DiagramScene example repeats an image to create a grid. It may or may not be difficult to snap objects to such a grid.

Comment: That's true, perhaps better to create a grid of squares. I do that in one of my apps using a QGraphicsItemGroup with each grid cell belonging to the group.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a while for something like this, and finally managed to cook up a "minimal" working example with Python `wx`, utilizing `wx.lib.ogl` and its `Diagram` and `ShapeCanvas` classes. The code (below) results with something like this:

[image: test.png]

Note:

- The app starts with the circle added; press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to add rectangles at random position
- Click an object to select it (to show handles); to deselect it, click the object again (clicking the background has no effect) - this is functionality of `ogl`
- The grid is drawn "manually"; however the snapping-to-grid is functionality of `ogl`
- Snap-to-grid only works automatically when moving shapes with mouse drag; for other purposes you must manually call it
- Snap-to-grid - as well as resizing of shape by handles - works in respect to the center of each shape (not sure if `ogl` allows for changing that anchor to, say, bottom left corner)

The example uses a `MyPanel` class that does its own drawing, and inherits both from `ogl.ShapeCanvas` and from `wx.Panel` (though the mixin with `wx.Panel` can be dropped, and the code will still work the same) - which is then added to a `wx.Frame`. Note the code comments for some caveats (such as the use of `ogl.ShapeCanvas` blocking all key events, unless a `SetFocus` is performed on that widget first).

The code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.ogl as ogl
import random

# tested on wxPython 2.8.11.0, Python 2.7.1+, Ubuntu 11.04

# started from:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756896/drawing-to-panel-inside-of-frame-in-wxpython/27804975#27804975

# see also:
# wxPython-2.8.11.0-demo/demo/OGL.py
# https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/186203/creating-editable-drawing-objects-in-wxpython
# http://gscept.com/svn/Docs/PSE/Milestone%203/code/trunk/python_test/src/oglEditor.py
# http://nullege.com/codes/search/wx.lib.ogl.Diagram
# http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40w%40e%40web2cms-HEAD%40web2py%40gluon%40contrib%40pyfpdf%40designer.py/465/wx.lib.ogl.Diagram/python
# https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/204969/setfocus-on-canvas-not-working
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538769/how-do-you-draw-a-grid-and-rectangles-in-python
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794496/snapping-to-pixels-in-wxpython


# ogl.ShapeCanvas must go first, else TypeError:  Cannot create a consistent method resolution
class MyPanel(ogl.ShapeCanvas, wx.Panel):#(wx.PyPanel): #PyPanel also works
  def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, name="MyPanel"):
    super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)
    self.gridsize = 20 # in pixels
    # must have these (w. Diagram) if using ogl.ShapeCanvas:
    self.diagram = ogl.Diagram()
    self.SetDiagram(self.diagram)
    self.diagram.SetCanvas(self)
    # set up snap to grid - note, like this it works only for drag (relative to shape center), not for resize via handles!
    self.diagram.SetGridSpacing( self.gridsize )
    self.diagram.SetSnapToGrid( True )
    # initialize array of shapes with one element
    self.shapes = []
    self.MyAddShape(
      ogl.CircleShape(85), # diameter - drag marquee will not be visible if (diameter mod gridsize == 0), as it will overlap with the grid lines
      60, 60, wx.Pen(wx.BLUE, 3), wx.GREEN_BRUSH, "Circle"
      )
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN(self, self.OnKeyPressedM)
  def OnKeyPressedM(self, event):
    keyCode = event.GetKeyCode()
    print("MyPanel.OnKeyPressedM: %d"%(keyCode) )
    # insert a rectangle here on [SPACE]:
    if keyCode == wx.WXK_SPACE:
      randx = random.randint(1, 300)
      randy = random.randint(1, 200)
      if self.diagram.GetSnapToGrid():
        randx, randy = self.Snap(randx, randy) # must do snapping (if desired) manually, here at insertion!
      self.MyAddShape(
          ogl.RectangleShape(60, 20),
          randx, randy, wx.BLACK_PEN, wx.LIGHT_GREY_BRUSH, "Rect %d"%(len(self.shapes))
        )
      self.Refresh(False)
    event.Skip() # must have this, to have the MyFrame.OnKeyPressed trigger as well!
  def OnSize(self, event):
    #print("OnSize" +str(event))
    self.Refresh() # must have here!
    event.Skip()
  def DrawBackgroundGrid(self):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    #print(dc)
    rect = self.GetClientRect()
    rx, ry, rw, rh = rect
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.GetForegroundColour()))
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.GetForegroundColour()))
    # draw ("tile") the grid
    x = rx
    while x < rx+rw:
      y = ry
      dc.DrawLine(x, ry, x, ry+rh) # long (vertical) lines
      while y < ry+rh:
        dc.DrawLine(x, y, x+self.gridsize, y) # short (horizontal) lines
        y = y + self.gridsize
      x = x + self.gridsize
  def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self) # works
    self.DrawBackgroundGrid()
    # self.Refresh() # recurses here - don't use!
    # self.diagram.GetCanvas().Refresh() # blocks here - don't use!
    self.diagram.GetCanvas().Redraw(dc) # this to redraw the elements on top of the grid, drawn just before
  # MyAddShape is from OGL.py:
  def MyAddShape(self, shape, x, y, pen, brush, text):
    # Composites have to be moved for all children to get in place
    if isinstance(shape, ogl.CompositeShape):
      dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
      self.PrepareDC(dc)
      shape.Move(dc, x, y)
    else:
      shape.SetDraggable(True, True)
    shape.SetCanvas(self)
    shape.SetX(x)
    shape.SetY(y)
    if pen:  shape.SetPen(pen)
    if brush:  shape.SetBrush(brush)
    if text:
      for line in text.split('\n'):
        shape.AddText(line)
    #shape.SetShadowMode(ogl.SHADOW_RIGHT)
    self.diagram.AddShape(shape)
    shape.Show(True)
    evthandler = MyEvtHandler(self)
    evthandler.SetShape(shape)
    evthandler.SetPreviousHandler(shape.GetEventHandler())
    shape.SetEventHandler(evthandler)
    self.shapes.append(shape)
    return shape

# copyfrom OGL.pyl; modded
class MyEvtHandler(ogl.ShapeEvtHandler):
  def __init__(self, parent): #
    ogl.ShapeEvtHandler.__init__(self)
    self.parent = parent
  def UpdateStatusBar(self, shape):
    x, y = shape.GetX(), shape.GetY()
    width, height = shape.GetBoundingBoxMax()
    self.parent.Refresh(False) # do here, to redraw the background after a drag move, or scale of shape
    print("Pos: (%d, %d)  Size: (%d, %d)" % (x, y, width, height))
  def OnLeftClick(self, x, y, keys=0, attachment=0):
    # note: to deselect a selected shape, don't click the background, but click the shape again
    shape = self.GetShape()
    canvas = shape.GetCanvas()
    dc = wx.ClientDC(canvas)
    canvas.PrepareDC(dc)
    if shape.Selected():
      shape.Select(False, dc)
      #canvas.Redraw(dc)
      canvas.Refresh(False)
    else:
      redraw = False
      shapeList = canvas.GetDiagram().GetShapeList()
      toUnselect = []
      for s in shapeList:
        if s.Selected():
          # If we unselect it now then some of the objects in
          # shapeList will become invalid (the control points are
          # shapes too!) and bad things will happen...
          toUnselect.append(s)
      shape.Select(True, dc)
      if toUnselect:
        for s in toUnselect:
          s.Select(False, dc)
        ##canvas.Redraw(dc)
        canvas.Refresh(False)
    self.UpdateStatusBar(shape)
  def OnEndDragLeft(self, x, y, keys=0, attachment=0):
    shape = self.GetShape()
    ogl.ShapeEvtHandler.OnEndDragLeft(self, x, y, keys, attachment)
    if not shape.Selected():
      self.OnLeftClick(x, y, keys, attachment)
    self.UpdateStatusBar(shape)
  def OnSizingEndDragLeft(self, pt, x, y, keys, attch):
    ogl.ShapeEvtHandler.OnSizingEndDragLeft(self, pt, x, y, keys, attch)
    self.UpdateStatusBar(self.GetShape())
  def OnMovePost(self, dc, x, y, oldX, oldY, display):
    shape = self.GetShape()
    ogl.ShapeEvtHandler.OnMovePost(self, dc, x, y, oldX, oldY, display)
    self.UpdateStatusBar(shape)
    if "wxMac" in wx.PlatformInfo:
      shape.GetCanvas().Refresh(False)
  def OnRightClick(self, *dontcare):
    #self.log.WriteText("%s\n" % self.GetShape())
    print("OnRightClick")

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Custom Panel Grid Demo")
    # This creates some pens and brushes that the OGL library uses.
    # (else "global name 'BlackForegroundPen' is not defined")
    # It should be called after the app object has been created, but
    # before OGL is used.
    ogl.OGLInitialize()
    self.SetSize((300, 200))
    self.panel = MyPanel(self) #wx.Panel(self)
    self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(250,250,250))
    self.panel.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(127,127,127))
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_1.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.SetAutoLayout(1)
    self.Layout()
    self.Show(1)
    # NOTE: on my dev versions, using ogl.Diagram causes _all_
    # key press events, from *anywhere*, to stop propagating!
    # Doing a .SetFocus on the ogl.ShapeCanvas panel,
    # finally makes the Key events propagate!
    # (troubleshoot via run.py from wx python demo)
    self.panel.SetFocus()
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnKeyPressed) # EVT_CHAR_HOOK EVT_KEY_DOWN
  def OnKeyPressed(self, event):
    print("MyFrame.OnKeyPressed (just testing)")

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Those actions are not that difficult. All you really need for that is hit detection, which is not hard (is the cursor over the correct area? Okay, perform the operation then). The harder part is finding an appropriate *canvas widget* for the toolkit in use.

Comment: For Tkinter what you say is the hard part is pretty easy: use the Canvas widget.