# Snapping to pixels in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am creating a simple GUI to record points which are clicked on the image, using wxpython. However, i would like the click to be snapped to certain points on the image. Please suggest methods.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest to snap to a fixed scale grid is with something like:

```
snap_x = scale * round(x / scale)
snap_y = scale * round(y / scale)
```

where scale is the size of your grid, eg 10 pixels.

If the points are nonuniformly distributed, then find the closest based on the distance (or the square of the distance for efficiency reasons).

Comment: But, you are not 'snapping', you are only approximating the recorded point. How will that help?

Comment: That's what snapping is - picking the nearest point. Did you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at wxPython's [Object Graphics Library](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.ogl-module.html).  The documentation's a little sparse but the [Diagram class](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.ogl.Diagram-class.html) has direct support for snapping to grids; take a look at the [wxPython Demo's](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) Miscellaneous->OGL section for some ideas to get started.  I'm in the middle of a project w. OGL right now - it's great for what it does but like I said I find the documentation a little thin.

Comment: Please let me know of a better alternative, or possibly a good way to learn the wxpython.library.ogl module

Comment: @Vishwanath - the documentation for OGL is pretty sparse.  I found the wxPython demo code to be the most use; the demo code makes use of the snap to grid feature.  You might also look at the [wxPyWiki entry](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxOGL) on the subject, it's also got a few alternative packages to consider.