# Shape drag and Drop in wxPython

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I am trying to create a drag and drop app (like how the Unreal engine does with events - e.g. [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/Images/InteractiveExperiences/UMG/HowTo/DragAndDrop/UpdateDragDrop2.1.jpg)) in Python using wxPython Phoenix.

I have found this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538769/how-do-you-draw-a-grid-and-rectangles-in-python) which I have figured out how to adapt to make it draw a rectangle, but I can't figure out how to have connector nodes and to draw lines between the rectangles.

Can anyone link me a good tutorial or demo program please (which would be greatly appreciated) as a starting point.

Comment: Show me your rectangle drawing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might be helpful (DragImage demo file):

https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython-Classic/blob/master/demo/DragImage.py